# How can I fix the 'Unable to set property' error in MudBlazor's MudTable GroupRow?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I get an error when I want to change `TableGroupDefinition` of `MudTable` when a `MudSwitch` is checked.

The error is:
`Unable to set property Items on object of type MudBlazor.MudTableGroupRow`

```
<MudSwitch T="bool" Checked="IsInnerGroup" Color="Color.Primary" CheckedChanged="CheckedChanged">Change Grouping</MudSwitch>

@code {
   private static bool IsInnerGroup = true;

    private TableGroupDefinition<Element> SetGroupDefinition()
    {
        return new TableGroupDefinition<Element>()
            {
                GroupName = "Group",
                Indentation = false,
                Expandable = false,
                Selector = (e) => e.Group,
                InnerGroup = new TableGroupDefinition<Element>()
                {
                    GroupName = "Position",
                    Expandable = false,
                    Selector = (e) => e.Position
                }
            };
    }
}
```